# "Do not start the new instance" option doesn't work in Workload Scheduler Service

Tags: scheduler, ibm-cloud, workload

I tested the following trigger "Rerun option" in Bluemix Workload Scheduler Service. 
**"Rerun option": "Do not start the new instance"**
I think this option means that a new instance exits with an error if an instance is still running. But from my test result it seems to be like the other option "Queue the new instance": a new instance entered "Queued" status even though when another instance of the same is still running.
Is my understanding about "Do not start the new instance" options wrong?

**"Rerun option": "Do not start the new instance"**
[image]

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

the meaning of 'rerun option' is exactly what you are calling 'second option':
if a starting instance of a process found an instance of the same still running, it enters in queued state, it doesn't exit with an error message/state.
It is conceptually correct by this way: giving an error or a warning when there is not error/warning could be misleading.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. As I commented for the following answer, I'll try the option for scheduled flows.

Answer (score 0):

The behavior is what you expect, only for scheduled flows (f.i. if you schedule a run every 5 minutes, and one of the runs takes long than 5 minutes, the next run is skipped).

I agree that in case of "Run Now" not scheduled process the behavior should be what you expect and not the same as "Queue the new instance".

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I'll try the option for scheduled flows.